# Compare 2 integers in a do while loop

Tags: java

Write a program that has the user enter integers between 0 and 9999 until the user enters some integer twice.  Program should to the console window how many distinct integers were entered.

How do i make the condition for the while loop? Or how do i compare if 2 integers entered by user in a do while loop are equal?

```
int n1,n2,count=0;           
do {
     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter an int: ");
     n1= kb.nextInt();
     n2= kb.nextInt();
     count++;
} while(n1 != n2);
System.out.println("you entered " + count + "times");
```

This is why i tried

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Exactly. When I run it now it compares the integers needed in pairs and does not keep a history of what was entered

Comment: Just rewrite your question with relevent details , its not clear.

Comment: Don't complicate it for yourself, you can do this with a set, check my answer below and ask if something is unclear.

Comment: @LalitVerma I m sorry

Comment: NoOne is pro bro, just try your best to make it clear, by the way i have added an answer check and tell if this is correct @Constantine

Comment: @LalitVerma The program should ask user to enter integers until one integer was entered before and then it should print out the total numbers of integers the user entered. For example if the user enters 5, 9, 7, 4, 5 it should print out You entered 5 integers and it stops

Comment: @Constantine check it now

Answer (score 0):

If you use set you could implement it as follows:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[]args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

        System.out.print("Enter your number: ");

        while (set.add(in.nextInt())){
            System.out.print("Enter next number: ");
        }

        System.out.println("There are " + set.size() + " distinct numbers entered into a set.");

    }
}
```

Set add() method returns true if set didn't contain added element and element was successfully added, or false if Set already contained entered element and the element wasn't added. So we ask user for numbers until he enters one that is already contained in a Set (he entered it before) then we break from the loop and print out the size of elements in the Set, which will be the number of distinct elements user entered.

Comment: Thank you for this

Comment: This is by far the most readable answer so far, nice! I like how the `Set.add` makes any other local variables or if checks unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

//one class needs to have a main() method
public class Beta {
    // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        boolean doExist = false;
        int inputVal;
        do {
            System.out.print("\nEnter an Integer:");
            inputVal = kb.nextInt();
            doExist = list.contains(inputVal);
            if (!doExist) {
                list.add(inputVal);
            }

        } while (!doExist);

        System.out.println("The Number of Non Duplicate Integers:"+list.size());

    }
}
```